Flutter webview find difficulties to get PWA button action
I've a flutter app and this app also contain a pwa. I use in webview_flutter.
In pwa I have a button "share". What I need is:
When I tap on on this share button inside the pwa I need the flutter app open the share widget.
I start to try using method as addJavaScriptChannel, runJavaScript as in the code I add below.
The problem is that I can't get the click action of that button.
This button is make in this way by watching it in inspect.
I try several times, this is one of the latest times. I need to understand how to get the result. Also in different ways.
I can also contact the dev who create that button to change small things.
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:share_plus/share_plus.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

Widget inAppWebViewCustom({
  required String url,
  required SharedPreferences prefs,
  bool hideHeaderFooter = false,
}) {
  final RxBool isLoading = true.obs;
  final WebViewController controller = WebViewController();
  controller.setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted);
  controller.setBackgroundColor(const Color(0x00000000));
  Timer? timer;

  void saveGetTokenFunction({
    required bool hideHeaderFooter,
    required Rx<bool> isLoading,
    required WebViewController controller,
    required SharedPreferences prefs,
  }) async {
    isLoading.value = false;
    if (hideHeaderFooter) {
      await controller.runJavaScript('''
          document.querySelector('header').style.display = 'none';
          document.querySelector('footer').style.display = 'none';
        ''');
    }
    final Object? accessToken = await controller.runJavaScriptReturningResult(
      'localStorage.getItem("accessToken");',
    );
    if (accessToken != null &&
        accessToken != '' &&
        !accessToken.toString().contains('null') &&
        appToken.value != accessToken.toString()) {
      await prefs.setString(kAccessToken, accessToken.toString());
      timer?.cancel();
      appToken.value = accessToken.toString().replaceAll('"', '');
    } else {
      if (appToken.value != '') {
        await controller.runJavaScript(
          'window.localStorage.setItem("accessToken", "${appToken.value})";',
        );
        timer?.cancel();
      }
    }
  }
  controller.addJavaScriptChannel(
    'mychannel',
    onMessageReceived: (JavaScriptMessage message) {
      if (message.message == 'share') {
        Share.share('Text to share', subject: 'subject');
      }
    },
  );

  controller.setNavigationDelegate(
    NavigationDelegate(
        onProgress: (int progress) async {
          if (progress == 100) isLoading.value = false;
        },
        onPageStarted: (String url) async {
          if (appToken.value != null &&
              appToken.value != '' &&
              !appToken.value.toString().contains('null')) {
            await controller.runJavaScript(
              'window.localStorage.setItem("accessToken", "${appToken.value})";',
            );
          }


        },
        onPageFinished: (String url) async {
          timer = Timer.periodic(
            const Duration(seconds: 1),
            (Timer t) => saveGetTokenFunction(
              isLoading: isLoading,
              controller: controller,
              prefs: prefs,
              hideHeaderFooter: hideHeaderFooter,
            ),
          );
        },
        onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {},
        onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {
          return NavigationDecision.navigate;
        },
      onUrlChange: (UrlChange UrlChange) async {

        await controller.runJavaScript('''
      const button = document.getElementsByClassName('MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-text MuiButton-textInherit MuiButton-sizeMedium MuiButton-textSizeMedium MuiButton-colorInherit MuiButton-disableElevation MuiButton-root MuiButton-text MuiButton-textInherit MuiButton-sizeMedium MuiButton-textSizeMedium MuiButton-colorInherit MuiButton-disableElevation css-1a0ejbe'); 
      mychannel.postMessage('share');
      ''');
      },
        ),
  );

  controller.loadRequest(Uri.parse(url));

  return Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      if (isLoading.value)
        const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
            color: AppColors.primary,
          ),
        )
      else
        Container(),
      WebViewWidget(controller: controller),
    ],
  );
}



